# LINQ Join to find items NOT IN a list

Tags: c#, linq

How do I use LINQ across Queryable and non-Queryable data?

With the following code I want to end up with a list of unselected users, i.e. everyone in allUsers that is not in selected.

```
public IQueryable<CompanyUser> FindAllUsersNotAssignedTothisCompany(int companyID)
{
    var allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    var selected = db.CompanyUsers.Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID);
    ...?
}
```

I effectively want a list of User ID's and Names suitable for use in a DropDownList (ASP.NET MVC)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that both `allUsers` and `selected` are of the same type, You can do this using **[Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)**

```
public IQueryable<CompanyUser> FindAllUsersNotAssignedTothisCompany(int companyID)
{
    var allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    var selected = db.CompanyUsers.Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID);
    return allUsers.Except(selected);
}
```

However if db.CompanyUsers already has all the users and all you need is to retrieve the users that do not have the companyID in question just:

```
return db.CompanyUsers.Where(c => c.CompanyID != companyID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in one line:

```
db.CompanyUsers.Where(c => !allUsers.Any(d=> d.CompanyID == a.companyID))).ToList();
```